# Tracking Opt-out flow for app that is only a wrapped WebView

Tags: ios, tracking, privacy

I have an iOS app that only wraps a website and registers for push notifications. It was released in around January.

I'm trying to release a new version with minimal fixes but it gets rejected because:

> The app privacy information you provided in App Store Connect indicates you collect data in order to track the user, including User ID. However, you do not use App Tracking Transparency to request the user's permission before tracking their activity.

The app does not do tracking. However inside the WebView the webpage uses Segment so the user behavior can be analyzed. Information is not shared with 3rd parties.

My question is. Does showing a WebView where there is a cookies opt-out flow already still counts as tracking? Can I just remove the tracking from the app privacy information so I don't need to implement any flow?

My other question is that if it still counts as tracking then do I need to somehow reject cookies if the user declines tracking outside the WebView? How do I do that?

My third question is that if there is any chance if I categorize my changes as a hotfix (login flow is broken so it is a hotfix), can I postpone dealing with this tracking issue?